# Count collisions in Corona SDK / Lua...?

Tags: timer, lua, count, coronasdk, collision

I have a short question related to design patterns. During collisions, an event is dispatched multiple times, which is why you obviously have to count them, to make it stable. My question :

I always end up just incrementing a counter and reset it with a short delay in each collision, which leads to bulky event listeners. Does anybody have a more elegant and overseeable way? They can get quite hard to debug sometimes.

As always, thanks for your help in advance!

Greetings, Nils

Comment: Do you can provide some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idurniat, you asked for code. Here is an example of the common problem:

```
local physics = require("physics")
local object = display.newRect(display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY, 100, 100)
physics.start()
physics.addBody(object, "static", {isSensor = true})
function object.collision(self, event)
  if event.phase == "began" then
    print("log")
  end
end
```

Now, when a dynamic physics object hits the rectangle, there will be printed several times "log". Because of this, for example transitions start multiple times and make a mess. And handling this with a counter and a timer is quite tricky.

Thanks in advance!

Greetings, Nils